# Unknown or bad timezone Carbon createFromTimestamp

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, php-carbon

I am converting the format for my date string to carbon but got an error Unknown or bad timezone when using createFromTimestamp

```
public function getEndAttribute(){
       $timezone = 'Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh'; //UTC+7
       if(empty($this->end_date)){
            $timestamp = Carbon::createFromTimestamp('Y-m-d H:i:s','2016-01-01 00:00:00',new \DateTimeZone($timezone));
       }else{
            $timestamp = Carbon::createFromTimestamp('Y-m-d H:i:s',$this->end_date,new \DateTimeZone($timezone));
       }
       return $timestamp;
    }
```

`Carbon::createFromTimestamp(strtotime($this->start_date));`
works for me but it seems to be 7 hours lower from my time (it seems to have been rolled back to UTC+0 <=> UTC+7)

```
2023-04-20 16:37:27 <=> Thu, 20 Apr 2023 09:37:27 GMT
```

Thank advance